# Regex match string while ignoring special chars Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

trying to write a regex matching string who contains a certain string while ignoring all 'special characters' like (?/@#%!^',. etc...

example:

Base string: Home

Match with: Ho'me or Home or Home!

Do not match with: rHomer

so far tried :

[a-zA-Z0-9 ](Home)

meaning just letters and numbers AND my string to match, of course this doesn't work

Comment: *... just letters and numbers...* but `'` isn't a letter or number, right?

Comment: exactly right!!

Comment: Scripting language?

Comment: Edit: javascript

Comment: Do you want all special characters or only the 2 mentioned above? please try to elaborate more for your own sake.

Comment: Thanks @AHTm edited my question, want all special characters, or, on the contrary include only letters and numbers

Comment: Do you mean `/^Home$/.test(my_input.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, ''))`?

Comment: Have you checked [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51631124/3832970)? It is more efficient than trying to match arbitrary chars in between known chars as pattern expansion or backtracking will most probably cause catastrophic backtracking or time-out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` defines "special character", here's pattern you can try:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]*H[^a-zA-Z0-9]*?o[^a-zA-Z0-9]*?m[^a-zA-Z0-9]*?e
```

Comment: Wow, that looks like fun if I'm searching for a long string. By the way, does the `?` in `*?` do anything specific?

Comment: @torazaburo `*` - matches 0 or more occurences and `?` makes it non-greedy (lazy).

Comment: Actually what I was asking is why greediness is an issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace all non-letter chars and compare strings:

```js
var base="Home";
var input="Ho'me?!";
console.log(base == input.replace(/[^A-Z]+/gi, ''));
// To support Unicode, requires ECMAScript 2018 support
console.log(base == input.replace(/\P{L}+/gu, ''));
```

The `[^A-Z]` pattern matches all chars other than ASCII letters, and `\P{L}` matches any char other than a Unicode letter.

To only check against letters, digits and space, you may use respectively

```
 .replace(/[^A-Z0-9 ]+/gi, '')
 .replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+/gu, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to only match the word Home that might include special characters the following regex would do:

```
^H{1}[ome!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\-=\[\]\{\}\;':"\\\|,\.<>\/?]+$
```

The regex explained:

1. ^H{1} : String should start with H
2. [ome!@#\$%\^&*()_+-=[]{}\;':"\\|,.<>/?]+ : match o,m,e, and all special characters one or more times.